# Type of function which getting params type as parameter

Tags: c#, parameters

--Edited--

I wrote the following function -

```
 public static int params1(params int [] x) {
        return 1;
    }
```

I would like to pass this function to another function as parameter like this, but this is a compilation error -

```
    public static int Foo(Func<params int [], int> myMethodName) {
           return 1; 
}
```

How I supposed to pass this function to Foo function?

---

Actually, I should have described my problem with more details -

I did what you wrote to me, but I noticed that if I define parameter as params, then I call the function without this, there no problem.

This is the new code -

```
 public static int params1(params int [] x) {
    return 1;
}

        public static int Foo(Func<int [], int> myMethodName) {
           return myMethodName(); 
}
```

In this code there is compilation error(because, it must get the paramter which its type is int []), how can I solve that?

Comment: Just remove `params` from the `Func` definition

Comment: `params` is syntactic sugar telling the compiler of calling code to construct an array and populate it with the parameters. There's only really one parameter passed - that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question might be asking for one of these things:

1. If you are just trying to pass `params1` to `Foo`, remove the word `params` from the declaration of `Foo`:

   ```
   public static int Foo(Func<int [], int> myMethodName) {
       return 1; 
   }
   ```
2. If you want `Foo` to be able to call `myMethodName` like this:

   ```
   myMethodName(1, 2, 3);
   ```

   Then you need a custom delegate:

   ```
   public delegate int CustomDelegate(params int[] parameters);
   ```
3. If you want to only allow methods that accept a `params` parameter to be passed into `Foo`, there is no way to do this as far as I know.

Comment: @Shlomita To fix the error, just pass in an empty int array. `new int[0]`

Comment: This is possible solution, but I prefer not to do that because of the code design. I try to think about another solution

Comment: Done!! Thank you so much!!